# Issues in abstracting ImageView style into themes.xml

Tags: android, android-layout

Here's my original layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And I have extracted all but one of the ImageView layout into themes.xml:

```
<style name="MenuButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerVertical">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentRight">true</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
</style>
```

I then replaced the attributes of the `ImageView` above to be:

```
<ImageView
        style="@style/MenuButton"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"/>
```

My problems are:

1. The design preview in Idea complained it couldn't resolve the `MenuButton` style.
2. The app deployed and ran just fine on my device, but the `android:layout_centerVertical` attribute was not applied. The item floated to the top of the container.

I'm new to Android so I'm likely to have missed something fundamental. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Dont use these attributes in style

```
<item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
```

It may create problems.

Comment: I have taken that out of the style and kept it in the item but it's still incorrect. It's aligned to the right of the container, has the correct amount of right padding, but not vertically centered. I can't remember reading anywhere in the documentation not to include `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` in a style. I may have missed it though.